# AWS Codepipeline not loading java jar file of my lambda and breaking

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-codepipeline

**Overview**
Currently I'm working with AWS Codepipeline. I have developed a terraform code for creating a lambda, along with the java lambda code right beside. I want my codepipeline to to run everytime there's a change in my source bit bucket repo, build the terraform, and create the required lambda function and upload my java jar to my lambda.

**Problem**
My terraform code is working fine locally, it created a new function and uploaded my jar file in it. The problem is when I run my code in the code pipeline, the pipeline breaks, seemingly unable to load/find my target jar file. I have tried abs path, path.module and other solutions but nothing seems to work with my target jar file.
Here is a glimpse of the error:
[image]

Here is the project structure[image]

Here is the contents of my main.tf in the root directory:

```
# terraform modules
module "demo_java_lambda" {
  source = "./terraform-module/"
}
```

here are the contents of my lambda.tf.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "java_lambda_function" {
  runtime          = "${var.lambda_runtime}"
  filename      = "${path.module}/../target/code.zip"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.lambda_archive.output_base64sha256}"
  function_name = "java_lambda_function"
  handler          = "${var.lambda_function_handler}"
  timeout = 60
  memory_size = 256
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.iam_role_for_lambda.arn}"
  depends_on   = ["aws_cloudwatch_log_group.log_group"]

}

data "archive_file" "lambda_archive" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/../target/handler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
  output_path = "${path.module}/../target/code.zip"
}
```

My goal is to be able to upload my jar file successfully in my lambda function while my code pipeline runs. I know there's some issue with the path, but any help would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: How are you building the jar? Normally this would be gitignored and you'd build the jar first, then run the Terraform code to zip the jar and create/update the Lambda function.

Comment: I'm building the jar locally, and uploading the code in my bitbucket. That's why I'm trying to load that jar file in my terraform code

Comment: Is the jar not gitignored? Eg it's in your git repo after you push and before the code pipeline runs?

Comment: Yes it is, target folder and *.jar files are in .gitignore. I guess I should remove them from there

Comment: it worked. My jar file was in gitignore. Thanks a lot

Comment: Unless this jar isn't going to change very often you would be better off to gitignore it and have your CI pipeline build it and pass it to the Terraform job instead. Otherwise you will quickly find that your git repo will explode in size. You could also potentially use git-lfs to minimise the problems there but the general practice is to only have the source in repos and build compiled artifacts and pass them to where they need to be.